# Youtube api в ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewpager, youtube-api

Добрый день.Есть следующая проблема с интеграцией youtube api. При нажатии на плей в видео, через две секунды становится на паузу. Сам плеер находится во фрагменте , который в ViewPager. Поиск по гулу подсказал что нужно запускать видео когда фрагмент станет видимым пользователю. Во ViewPager у меня находятся фрагменты трех разных типов. Я добавил слушатель перелистывания фрагментов, и в нем, если это фрагмент с видео, я запускаю видео.

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            if(adapter.getItem(position) instanceof VideoFragment){

                VideoFragment videoFragment = (VideoFragment) adapter.getItem(position);
                videoFragment.playVideo();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
```

Этот метод сработал. но это в режиме перелистывания. А если открываю viewpager сразу на фрагменте с видео , проблема не исчезает. Для решения этой проблемы я пробовал реализовывать слушатель инициализации плеера, с фрагмента, и когда плеер инициализирован. запускать через метод фрагмента видео. не сработало.

```
VideoFragment videoFragment = new VideoFragment(new VideoFragment.VideoFragmentListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void videoFragmentCreate() {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "videoFragmentCreate ");

                        if(adapter.getItem(positionArticle) instanceof VideoFragment){
                            VideoFragment videoFragment = (VideoFragment) adapter.getItem(positionArticle);
                            videoFragment.playVideo();
                        }
                    }
                });

                adapter.addFragmentForward(videoFragment);

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pagerArticles">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ProgressBar
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/progressVideo"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

            <TextView
                android:text="annotation_video"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/annotation_video"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/annotation_video"
                android:id="@+id/layout"
                android:layout_height="235dp">

        <fragment
            android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
            android:id="@+id/youtubesupportfragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:text="text_video"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/text_video"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layout"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: в плеера есть такая особенность, - если его перекрывает любой другой элемент, то он автоматически останавливает воспроизведение. Даже если там перекрытие в 1 пиксель, он не будет нормально работать. Покажите разметку VideoFragment

Comment: Разметку добавил. Но дело в том что этот этот же фрагмент в обычном контейнере работает нормально. А в ViewPager не хочет.

Comment: разве ваше "<TextView android:text="text_video" ..." не накладывается на  YouTubePlayerSupportFragmen?

Comment: android:layout_below="@+id/layout" этой строчкой этот текст ниже layout ,в котором находится YouTubePlayerSupportFragment. А этой android:layout_marginTop="5dp" ниже еще на 5dp

Comment: напиши мне на почту martsinkevych@gmail.com договоримся о подключении к вашему пк и исправлении ошибки